# Move iMovie project to an external drive

Tags: macos, imovie

I have loaded some camcorder cassette tapes into iMovie and have tried to move the video projects to a back up disk to free up space on my hard drive. The help menu says that if you choose  "move project and events" it will move the projects and delete them from the hard drive. So far all I've been able to do is move the event and It doesn't free up any hard drive space. What am I doing wrong?